# Tomee with Arquillian using Postgres DB user lacks privilege or object not found

Tags: postgresql, jpa, java-ee-6, apache-tomee, jboss-arquillian

I have a problem when running arquillian tests against postgres db using tomee.
With all the info on the web I'm still struggling to get the problem solved.

```
javax.ejb.EJBException: The bean encountered a non-application exception; nested exception is: 
    Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or object not found: CREDENTIALS
Error Code: -5501
Call: SELECT ID, PASSWORD, USERNAME FROM credentials WHERE (USERNAME = ?)
    bind => [phil]
```

The DB:

> Name: registry
>
> Table: credentials
>
> Sits under manually created Schema: postgres

persistence.xml under directory *src/main/resources*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

  <persistence-unit name="registry" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>RegistryDS</jta-data-source>
    <non-jta-data-source>UnmanagedRegistryDS</non-jta-data-source>
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>za.co.registry.client.login.Credentials</class>
    <properties>
      <property name="eclipselink.debug" value="OFF"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.weaving" value="static"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.logging.level.sql" value="FINE"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.logging.parameters" value="true"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.logging.logger" value="DefaultLogger"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

tomee.xml

```
<Resource id="RegistryDS" type="DataSource">
          jdbcDriver=org.postgresql.Driver
          jdbcUrl=jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/registry
          userName=postgres 
          password=postgres 
          JtaManaged=true
</Resource>
<Resource id="UnmanagedRegistryDS" type="DataSource">
          jdbcDriver=org.postgresql.Driver
          jdbcUrl=jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/registry
          userName=postgres 
          password=postgres 
          JtaManaged=false
</Resource>
```

pom.xml extract for arquillian tests

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.openejb</groupId>
    <artifactId>arquillian-tomee-embedded</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency> 

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.3.Final</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.11</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

arquillian.xml extract

```
<container qualifier="tomee" default="true">
    <configuration>
        <property name="httpPort">-1</property>
        <property name="stopPort">-1</property>
        <property name="dir">target/apache-tomee-remote</property>
        <property name="appWorkingDir">target/arquillian-test-working-dir</property>
        <property name="properties" />
    </configuration>
</container>
```

The `ServiceTest.java` file when loading the resources.

```
    @Deployment
    public static WebArchive createDeployment() {
        WebArchive webArchive = newArchive();
        webArchive.addClasses(Credentials.class);
        webArchive.addAsResource("META-INF/persistence.xml");
        webArchive.addAsResource("META-INF/beans.xml");
        return webArchive;
    }
```

And last the test `findCredentialsByUsernameTest` method in `ServiceTest.java`

```
@Test
public void findCredentialsByUsernameTest() {
    Credentials login = LoginService.findByUsername("phil");
    Assert.assertNotNull(login);
}
```

I do not start or end any `EntityTransaction`'s in the test class.

It works injecting a EJB when the DB call in the service is removed.
What am I missing in the config or doing wrong for this not to be working?

Comment: "*user lacks privilege or object not found: CREDENTIALS*" is **not** a Postgres error message (the corresponding Postgres error would be "*relation "credentials" not found*"). The error message is typical for **HSQLDB** though. Are you sure you are connecting to the right database?

Comment: Hi @a_horse_with_no_name, I indicated Postgres because it is part of the scenario and my environment. It might read a bit funny in the title. I think I'm connecting to the right DB, but that is why I supplied all the info above for someone to help and see if I'm doing the config right.

Comment: Well, if you are connecting to an embedded HSQLDB then it won't help that your Postgres database is setup correctly.

Comment: I'm not sure then that I'm doing the config right. Nowhere do I connect to a embedded db when doing test, from what I know. Must I connect to a embedded db when using Arquillian/Integration tests? I thought that when I have arquillian tomee embedded setup it wil use the datasource as well for my tests.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I know what I did wrong.

I need to run the tests against a embedded db.

The steps that I followed to get Arquillian tests to work against a embedded db;

Removed un-managed data source from tomee.xml, I added it because I wanted to use it for my tests. The other data source is still there because it is used when deploying to tomee to connect to postgres db.

```
<Resource id="UnmanagedRegistryDS" type="DataSource">
          jdbcDriver=org.postgresql.Driver
          jdbcUrl=jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/registry
          userName=postgres 
          password=postgres 
          JtaManaged=false
</Resource>
```

I'm going to connect to HSQLDB.

```
HSQLDB (HyperSQL DataBase) is the leading SQL relational database software written in Java. It offers a small, fast multithreaded and transactional database engine with in-memory and disk-based tables and supports embedded and server modes
```

Next I create a second persistence.xml in *src/test/resources* called test-persistence.xml. Keep in mind the persistence-unit name *testDatabase* it is going to be used in the *arquillian.xml* file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="test" transaction-type="JTA">
        <jta-data-source>testDatabase</jta-data-source>
        <class>za.co.registry.client.login.Credentials</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="openejb.jpa.init-entitymanager" value="true" />
            <property name="openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings" value="buildSchema(ForeignKeys=true)" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

The arquillian.xml, I'm setting the *testDatabase* persistence unit properties in the file. See below under properties.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<arquillian
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian/arquillian_1_0.xsd">
    <container qualifier="openejb-embedded" default="true">
        <configuration>
            <property name="httpPort">-1</property>
            <property name="stopPort">-1</property>
            <property name="dir">target/apache-tomee-remote</property>
            <property name="appWorkingDir">target/arquillian-test-working-dir</property>
            <property name="properties">
                testDatabase = new://Resource?type=DataSource
                testDatabase.JdbcUrl = jdbc:hsqldb:mem:my-datasource
             </property>
        </configuration>
    </container>
</arquillian>
```

Configuring my `ServiceTest.java` file to include the new persistence.xml file.

```
webArchive.addAsWebInfResource("META-INF/test-persistence.xml", "persistence.xml");
webArchive.addAsResource("META-INF/beans.xml");
```

Now I can run the `findCredentialsByUsernameTest`  method.

```
    @Test
    public void findCredentialsByUsernameTest() {
        //create credentials first
        Credentials newCredentials = loginService.newCredentials(new Credentials("john", "password"));

        //search for credentails
        Credentials login = loginService.findByUsername("john");
        Assert.assertNotNull(login);
        Assert.assertEquals(newCredentials.getUsername(), login.getUsername());
    }
```